# Flexboxes, Chrome and unexpected scroll bar

Tags: css, google-chrome, scrollbar, flexbox

I'm using flexible layout like this:

```css
/* VBOX */
.vbox {
    background-color:gray;
    border:4px solid black;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    flex:none;
    flex-flow:column nowrap;
    display:flex;
    overflow:auto;
}
.vbox>.stretched {
    flex:1 0 auto;
}

/* HBOX */
.hbox {
    background-color:red;
    border:4px solid darkred;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    flex:none;
    flex-flow:row nowrap;
    display:flex;
    overflow:auto;
}
.hbox>.stretched {
    flex:1 0 auto;
}

/* ITEM */
.item {
    background-color:lightblue;
    border:0.25em solid blue;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    flex:none;
    height:2em;
    width:7em;
}
```

```html
<div class="vbox" style="width:10em;height:10em;">
    <div class="hbox">
        <div class="item"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="hbox stretched">
        <div class="item"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="hbox">
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Unlike IE and FireFox, Chrome adds a vertical scroll bar to the last horizontal container (it seems like horizontal scroll bar height is not taken into account). http://jsfiddle.net/31dLqdms/8/
How to fix that using CSS only?

### Hint:

The following script, which toggles "flex" CSS-property, seems to solve the problem (but the content of the boxes will be changed dynamically so it's not a solution) http://jsfiddle.net/31dLqdms/11/ :

```js
var items = $('.hbox:not(.stretched)');
setTimeout(function () {
    items.addClass('stretched');
    setTimeout(function () {
        items.removeClass('stretched');
    }, 500);
}, 500);
```

Comment: I'm talking about the vertical scroll bar (on bottom-right).

Answer (score 0):

Ok now I get what you mean.  The closest I could get to solving the problem is below:
http://jsfiddle.net/31dLqdms/9/

css:

```
.vbox {
    background-color:gray;
    border:4px solid black;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    flex:none;
    flex-flow:column nowrap;
    display:flex;
    overflow:auto;
}
.test{
    overflow-x:scroll;
    background-color: darkred;
}
```

html:

```
<div class="test">
    <div class="hbox">
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I don't think there's a lot you can do about how a browser deals with the scroll bars so what I did was set the hbox's overflow to visible and then wrapped that in a container div which had the overflow set to scroll.  This way the scroll bar appears on the container div and not the hbox.

(I then had a problem with the background colour which I fixed ussing css).

Is this more like what you were looking for?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I'm adding the contents dynamically, and additional HTML-wrappers lead to another scrolling bugs in IE. I noticed than toggling the "flex" property strangely helps. See my edit http://jsfiddle.net/31dLqdms/11/

Comment: Ahh didn't realize it was dynamically made.  I didn't think that flex would be the issue.